# Keep comments in webpack?

Tags: minify, webpack-2

So consider the following script command to run via `npm run`: `webpack -p --optimize-minimize`

Is there any way to say: **Keep comments**?

*webpack version 2 is used.*

In most applications you would not want to keep comments, but in this particular case I want to keep them, while still minifying the "script" Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack's `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` has a [couple of options](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/#options) which might fit your needs.

`comments` options accepts a regex or function to tell `UglifyJs` which comment to preserve.

`extractComments` let you even extract the comments to separate txt files.

Set it up like this:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        comments: true, // or function/regex
        // Further UglifyJs config
    })
],
```

Comment: Error: webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead.